# Google Android People error Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin, signing, google-people-api

Good day.I am trying to call the api method.All goes good,the screen of login is being represented to user with request of its circles,and boom as soon as im trying to get the people list from circles it goes with error always!

```
Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}
```

I dont know what it causing and by googling i found nothing closer to my issue so ill post an code how i do call this method.
Here how i build and call it.

```
 public synchronized GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient(final Activity activity) {
    GoogleSignInOptions gGoogleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gGoogleSignInOptions)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                    Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, "me").setResultCallback(new ResultCallbacks<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(@NonNull People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Person person = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer().get(0);
                            Log.d("fasfafasfsafasfas", "onSuccess: " + person);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Status status) {
                            if (status.hasResolution()) {
                                try {
                                    // !!!
                                    status.startResolutionForResult(activity, 100);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                                }
                            }
                            Log.d("fasfafasfsafasfas", "onFailure: " + status);
                        }

                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
    return mGoogleApiClient;
}
```

It always goes into onFailure callback with network error..I dont know whats wrong i have typed...
here is permissions required in manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
```

So please do tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: guys???? no one have a clue?

Comment: Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195264/google-plus-unable-to-load-person)? Why didn't it help?

Comment: it does not help as all api keys are set correctly

Comment: because if not set correctly,the login page would not be visible to the user but it is visible

Comment: and plus that is related to self person and im loading the CIRCLES of a person not self,i am able to get self person

Comment: ARRRR IM GOING CRAZY ALREADY ready to smash the shit out of that idiotic google developers who ever put the documentation without reasonable information!DAMN THEM!

Comment: PEOPPPLE HELP ME!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone encounter same issue here is the solution.You do not need to specify "me" when getting circles,meanwhile specify NULL to it like this

```
  Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null
                    ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallbacks<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(@NonNull People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
                            int personCount = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer().getCount();
                            Log.d("fasfafasfsafasfas", "onSuccess: " + personCount);
                            for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
                                Person eachPerson = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer().get(i);
                                Log.d("fasfafasfsafasfas", "onSuccess: " + eachPerson.getImage().getUrl());
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Status status) {
                            if (status.hasResolution()) {
                                try {
                                    status.startResolutionForResult(activity, requestCode);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                                }
                            }
                            Log.d("fasfafasfsafasfas", "onFailure: " + status);
                        }

                    });
```